# Ambiguous method overloading for method java.io.File#<init>

Tags: android, gradle

I am getting the following error messgae.I have worked with my existing module now it is giving the error, sdk path is configured properly in property file. i have rebuild and clean the project but not getting the solution.

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'url -script' line: 30

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Ambiguous method overloading for method java.io.File#<init>.
  Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null, class java.lang.String] due to overlapping prototypes between:
    [class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String]
    [class java.io.File, class java.lang.String]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 33s
```

Comment: Google `due to overlapping prototypes between`. There are plenty of solutions available.

Comment: The compiler can't decide whether the `null` you have passed in is of type `String` or `File`. You could fix the compile error by adding a type cast. But apart from that, it does not make sense to pass in `null` for a `File` constructor.

Comment: @Henry where i have to check or typecast , actually i am not able to find where i am missing.

Comment: Have a closer look here: Script 'http://mspm1bapps1349:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases//com/mdt/neuro/tf/CommonSpockTestFramework/1.0.235/CommonSpockTestFramework-1.0.235-licensure.gradle' line: 30